# Linear Gradient In React-Native

Tags: android, css, react-native

I have a component and I want a linear gradient from right bottom to top left in react native, I tried using  from 'react-native-linear-gradient' but it's not working.

Component :

// render return

```
   return( 
      <LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} >
       <View style={styles.container}>
         <View  style={styles.topPart}>
           <Header ></Header>
           <Content ></Content>
        </View>  
        <Footer style={styles.footer}></Footer>
      </View>
    </LinearGradient>  
);
```

Please guide how to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After installing `react-native-linear-gradient` library by:

```
npm install --save react-native-linear-gradient
```

Try to link your project's all dependencies as,

```
react-native link
```

And make sure you are importing `LinearGradient` as,

```
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
```

And the last but most important thing set some `flex` value to your `LinearGradient`,

```
<LinearGradient 
     colors={['#6e45e2', '#88d3ce']}
     style = { styles.container }>

          <View>
               //your elements here
          </View> 
 </LinearGradient>
```

Your LinearGradient `style` as,

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
  }
});
```

**Note** I am sure your gradient is not visible because of `flex` value, just add it. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve an angled gradient by setting start and end positions as props. In your case, those should be:

```
start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
```

If you mean that you don't see any gradient at all, did you link the library according to the install instructions?

Comment: it is not showing any gradinet at all , I have installed the library using npm  and imported it in my project , what else i have to do

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the library using npm and imported it in your project, you still have to link the library. Link the library by running,

```
react-native link
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<LinearGradient colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']} start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 1}}>
....
</LinearGradient>
```

This wll pretty much solve what you are looking for.